# Azure bicep - App Service Plans names and tiers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

When working with, for example, Azure Function and bicep, the fuction needs an App Service Plan and this plan needs a `sku`:

```
resource MyHostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: MyAppPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: ? 
    tier: ?
  }
}

resource MyFunction1 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: MyAppPlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp' 
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: MyHostingPlan.id
    ...
```

There doesn't seem to be a 1 to 1 mapping between what's in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/app-service/linux/#pricing and the names of the tier and SKUs for bicep scripts. For example:

- The consumption plan is "Y1"/"Dynamic"
- P1v2 seem to be `"sku": { "name": "P1v2", "tier": "PremiumV2" }`

Neither of these two are explicitly stated in the pricing table and while for P1v2 *maybe* one could guess, for the consumption plan this is not obvious at all.

Q: What is correct process of finding out the strings for the *name* and *tier` for an App Service Plan to use in a bicep script?

Answer (score 1):

- Consumption is Y1,
- Pxv2 is the App Service Plan (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/#pricing)
- EPx are the Function Premium Plans (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/#pricing)

*x defines the scale of a single instance.

Best place to look this up is the Azure Portal in the Scaling Section of the Function/App Service Plan

[image]

> Note: All those plans are different. While the consumption plan
> provides event based auto-scale at pay-what-you-use rates, the
> function premium plan offers the same but at fixed per instance prices
> with additional features (e.g. network integration, no-warmup time,
> etc).  The App Service Plan is different than those two plans. No
> event-based autoscaling but is great if you have functions and unused
> capacity at an existing plan.